# Modelling equivalent classes by Protege 3.5

Tags: protege, equivalence-classes

I am using Protege 3.5 ontology editor. I have two classes "ProcessName" and "AvailableProcess". I would like to say that these two classes are equivalent, i.e. that they have the same class extension (same instances in both classes). I would use it in a way that I create new instances to the "AvailableProcess" class, and these instances would then also be members of "ProcessName" class. How can I model that in Protege 3.5.? I saw that newer versions of Protege have this "Equivalent To" desription, but I can not find that in Protege 3.5.

Thanks!

BR,
Eeva

Comment: This is probably one of the first few times I've seen a correct use of the tag "equivalence-classes." That said, you're going to have to actually give us a code sample of what you did. StackOverflow isn't for doing your work for you. It's for helping you do your work better and answering direct questions to direct problems. As is, your question is a bit vague. Can you edit it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I modified the question to give a bit more details. I am just wondering if there is such method in Protege 3.5. to say that two classes are equivalent? I have tried to seach for it, but can not find it. I know that in other protege-versions it exists.

Comment: One way to achieve the desired result is to declare ProcessName and AvailableProcess subclass of each other - although I think Protege 3.5. should have a shortcut to do so.

Comment: Partially unrelated: why are you restricted to 3.5? If you're creating OWL ontologies, I would recommend Protege 5 - 3.5 is seriously outdated.

Comment: Thanks Ignazio for your answer! And sorry for the late reply, I was on travels.

Comment: Why I am using Protege 3.5 instead of 5 is that 3.5 seems to have more intuitive UI to model instances than 5. In 3.5 I see directly the properties that should be defined for an instance belonging to a certain class, while in Protege 5 I can select any properties for the instance. Or is this something that could be configured in Protege 5?